# Bitwise operations on lengthy Hex and ascii strings with Python

Tags: python, hex, bit-manipulation, xor

I am looking for a way that I can do bitwise operations (for crypto so mostly xor) on hex strings which could possibly be longer than I would want to fit in a Long.  As an example I could have a lengthy hex literal I want to xor with other data.  Below is an example of what I want to do and how I am doing it now but I believe at some limit the computer will hit it's limit in what it can put in Long so how can I do this more robustly?

```
#assuming lengths of messages are correct and key length as well
old_hex = "top secret ascii message".encode('hex')
encoded = "09e1c5f70a65ac56e55ac519458e7e53f36" #a literal hex encoded string
key_hex = int(old_hex,16) ^ int(encoded,16) #this currently works because this fits in Long
new_hex = "my new message to send 2".encode('hex')
ans_hex = key_hex ^ int(new_hex,16)

print 'old message in hex: 0x'+old_hex
print 'found a key in hex: '+str(hex(key_hex))
print 'new message in hex: 0x'+new_hex
print 'new message encode: '+str(hex(ans_hex))
```

So I will want to do XORs on longer strings that this and I am afraid they will not fit in a Long variable so how can I get around this?  Do I have to break the string up into smaller chunks and do each part through the operation?

Comment: how long are your strings? python ints go on forever. `2 ** 4096` fits into an int

Comment: So if I paste in a paragraph or a whole page of hex you don't think it will hit the limit when converting to an int?

Comment: it shouldnt. if youre doing a simple xor cipher, just xor each character individually, if by some crazy method, you overflow a python int. otherwise, use ints as defined in the standard of the algorithm youre implementing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I believe at some limit the computer will hit it's limit in what it can put in Long

Yes, there is a limit but that limit is **huge**. Eventually you will run out of memory, but the same could happen with strings. Python's integer type will work fine.

Comment: ok, thanks I figured it would be similar to how C did things but I guess not.  Good to know.